# Как повернуть пулю в направление её движения?

Tags: c#, unity3d, математика

Сколько не гуглил и не искал - всё не то.
Суть вопроса: у пули есть поле direction, обозначающее направление её движения.
Проблема в том, что пуля смотрит не в направлении своего движения( 1 картинка), а я хочу так, как на второй. Работаю в 2D.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так как ориентация пули-то задаётся?

Answer (score 1):

Pro Guide:

1. Дважды кликаем по спрайту и в windows он откроется в программе Windows Photo Viewer или Photos(Фотографии).
2. Нажимаем на кнопку поворота изображения на 90 градусов, которая обычно в виде закругленной стрелочки.

Готово

Если случилось такое несчастье, что спрайт часть атласа, то можно повернуть `GameObject` спрайта в префабе.

Если спрайт и есть префаб, что убираешь `SpriteRenderer` с головного `GameObject` префаба и добавляешь дочерний, который можно вертеть.

Answer (score 0):

Можно задать пуле вектор скорости в определенном направлении:

```
object.velocity = new Vector2(x,y)
```

В свойствах объекта у пули будет свойство `Rotation`, там пуле задайте направление, повернув ее в нужную сторону.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).